# Google Cloud Speech Background Noise

Tags: noise-reduction

We are having some kiosks that are used to command or order.

However, in noisy/outdoor environment, Google Cloud Speech sometimes produces wrong speech or commands.

What can we do to improve accuracy and remove/reduce the noise negative effect?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the following public reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices) which explains that excessive background noise and echoes may reduce accuracy and to obtain optimal results from the Cloud Speech API, it is best position the microphone as close to the user as possible, particularly when background noise is present as the recognizer is designed to ignore background voices and noise without additional noise-canceling.

Comment: Thanks for your reply However we have tried but the accuracy improvement is not good. The key problem is noisy background and we can not move kiosk to quiet locations

Comment: As it is mentioned within the link [https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices] that I previously shared with you, "Excessive background noise and echoes may reduce accuracy". I understand that you cannot move the kiosk to a better place but to obtain a better result from the Cloud Speech API you need to find a way to decrease or to avoid the background noise as much as possible. At this point the issue isn't the API itself but the excessive noise.